# My omitRow function omits the wrong row

Tags: java, oop, matrix

This project involves three classes. Star creates the stars, Starfield creates a matrix of stars, and StarfieldSimualation is the runner
When I omit row 0, it omits the bottom row, instead of the top one. But, it works for rows 1-4. Thanks in advance for the help.

Starfield Code

```
public class Starfield 
  {
    private Star[][] Sky;
    public  Starfield(int rows, int cols)
    {
        if(rows < 0 || cols < 0)
            {
                rows = cols = 1;
            }
        Sky = new Star[rows][cols];
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String S = "";
        for (Star[] row: Sky)
        {
            for(Star X: row)
            {
                if(X != null)
                {
                    S+= X.getImage() + "\t";
                }
                else
                {
                    S += "- \t";
                }
            }
            S += "\n";      
        }


        return S;
    }
    public void addStar(String Image, String Constellation, int row, int col)
    {
        if(row < 0 || row >= Sky.length || col < 0 || col >= Sky[0].length)
        {
            return;
        }
        Sky[row][col] = new Star(Image, Constellation, row, col);
    }
    public Star[][] omitRow(int r)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        k = 0;
        Star[][] rowless = new Star[Sky.length - 1][Sky[0].length];
        for(i = 0; i < Sky.length-1; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < Sky[0].length; j++)
            {

                    k++;
            }
        }
        Star[] ans = new Star[k];
        k = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < Sky.length; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < Sky[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(i != r)
                {
                    ans[k] = Sky[i][j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }       
        k = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < rowless.length; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < rowless[0].length; j++)
            {

                if(i != r)
                {
                    rowless[i][j] = ans[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        return rowless;
    }
```

Star Code

```
public class Star 
{
    private Star[][] Sky;
    private String Image, Constellation;
    private int row, col;
    public Star(String I, String C, int r, int c)
    {
        Image = I;
        Constellation = C;
        row = r;
        col = c;
    }


    public String getImage()
    {
        return Image;
    }
    public String getConstellation()
    {
        return Constellation;
    }
    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }
    public int getCol()
    {
        return col;
    }


}
```

Starfield Simluation Code

```
    public class StarFieldSimulation
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Starfield theSky = new Starfield(5,4);

            theSky.addStar("*", "Orion", 2, 3);
            theSky.addStar("*", "Orion", 2, 2);
            theSky.addStar("*", "Orion", 2, 1);
            theSky.addStar("*", "Orion", 2, 0);
            theSky.addStar("*", "Orion", 1, 3);

            System.out.println("IT'S THE SKY EVERYONE");
            System.out.println(theSky.toString());
            Star[][] minusrow = new Star[4][4];
            minusrow = theSky.omitRow(4);

            System.out.println("A row has been removed");

            System.out.println();
            for(Star[] row: minusrow)
            {
                for(Star X: row)
                {
                    if(X != null)
                    {
                        System.out.print(X.getImage() + "\t");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("-\t");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("It's the sky again");
            System.out.println(theSky.toString());
}
```